# Plugin that displays small clock on web browser depending on page's country

Tags: web-browser, timezones

I'd like to know if there is a plugin or userscript that displays a small clock with the local timezone of the page you are visiting.

Comment: What if the page comes from a large site that uses a Content Delivery Network, or some  cloud service, cleverly load-balanced?

Comment: Hm... I guess user input +  domain info as fallback would be the best approach